# Many Submit buttons for the same html form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, submit-button

hope you fine and well,

i have the following form:

```
<form class="hidden-print"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">                                  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>         
                      <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>                 
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tr>
                 <?php           
                     $pdo = Database::connect();
                     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);          
                     $sql = "SELECT * from persons";             
                     $i=0;           
                     foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
                            echo'<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '    ">';                                                       
                            echo '<td>'. $row['Name'] . '</td>'; 
                            echo'<input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="' . $row['Name'] . '    ">';                                                                             
                            $i++;                          
                    }
                   Database::disconnect();                 
                   ?>                                                   
            </tr> 
            </table>
                 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send" >
            </form>
```

let me explain what happening here, my form is PHP_SELF so i post the data to the same page, i created a table inside the form which contains ID's and Names, i loop through the selected data and each row in the table will contain id and name of person, as you see, i defined the inputs name and id as arrays eg. name[] and id[] , and i have a submit button at the end of the form will post the arrays id[] and name[].

now what i want is to put an submit input in each row ! so when i click the submit button it will post just the id and the name  of the person in this row !

is this possible ?!

regards.

Comment: Yes it's possible, I use similar functionality in my sites. Just name the buttons thesamename and perform a switch for the value of the button.

Comment: thanks, could you give me a code ?!

Comment: well, yes I could but I'm not sure it would help you. I use a custom php framework that I built myself about 15 years ago and have continued to maintain over the years. however - I will answer the question with conceptual explanation, hopefully it's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using associative array in names e.g. `name[]`

Use counters:

`name[<?php echo $i;?>]`

And add submit buttons with the same

`<input type="submit" name="submit[<?php echo $i;?>]"/>`

In PHP, loop over `$_POST`.

And check index of submit button using `foreach` loop.

Use the same index for `name`, `id`, etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer updated with code:

```
<form class="hidden-print"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<?php
$pdo = Database::connect();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "SELECT * from persons";
$i=0;
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
 echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>'. $row['id'] . '</td>';
 echo'<input type="hidden" name="id['.$row['id'].'" value="' . $row['id'] . '    ">';
 echo '<td>'. $row['Name'] . '</td>';
 echo'<input type="hidden" name="name['.$row['id'].'" value="' . $row['Name'] . '    ">';
 ?>
 <td>
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send" name="send<?php echo $rowp['id'];?>" >
 </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
    ++$i;
}
Database::disconnect();
?>
            </tr> 
            </table>
            </form> 
<?php
if (! empty($_POST['send'])) {
 foreach ($_POST['send'] as $key => $posted) {
  $id = isset($_POST['id'][$key]) ? $_POST['id'][$key] : '';
  $name = isset($_POST['name'][$key]) ? $_POST['name'][$key] : '';
  // Do your SQL here.
 }
}
?>
```

> Note: HTML mark ups are used as it is, please correct it as per your needs.

Comment: thanks, but could you please show your suggestion in my code ?!

Comment: Glad to hear that. My little knowledge helped to solve an issue. You are welcome.